# proper way to redirect domain to another domain in apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    "DocumentRoot C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mysite"

    ServerName mysite.eu

    ServerAlias www.mysite.eu
    ServerAlias play.mysite.eu

    ServerAlias www.mysite.org
    ServerAlias play.mysite.org
    ServerAlias mysite.org

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Options -Indexes

</VirtualHost>
```

Why does this not automatically redirect all requests from mysite.org to mysite.eu?  And what would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is only used when someone goes to www.mysite.eu (which then needs to point to the server's IP) so that the web server knowns to use the vhost file to serve the request - i.e there is no redirection. If you want to redirect, use mod_rewrite, for example

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.org$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.eu" [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm, something's fighting with it.  When I put this in here, I see the status bar flash back and forth from mysite.org to mysite.eu before eventually giving up with this message:The page isn't redirecting properly  
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
        

        
        

  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.

Comment: that means you have an infinite redirection loop somewhere